# Proper subset of span of only one vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that $v_1,....,v_k$ are linearly independent if and only if for each $j\in\{1,...,k\}$: span$(v_1,..,v_{j-1},v_{j+1},..,v_k) \subsetneq$ span$(v_1,...,v_{j-1},v_j,v_{j+1},...,v_k)$

My first question is: Do I have to use induction in this case or could I simply let j be arbitrary and prove that the result holds for j?

Secondly, if I do use induction, what exactly is the base case? I know that for $j=1$ there is no vector in span$(v_1,..,v_{j-1},v_{j+1},..,v_k)$, what exactly is the result of that? Is the result the null vector?

Comment: 1. Yes, you could. 2. Nothing spans trivial vector space $\{0\}$.

Comment: Don't use induction. Note that $\subseteq$ is clear and what can you conclude from $v_j\in\operatorname{span}$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen "$v_j \in span$", the span of which vectors? I assume you mean span$(v_1,...,v_j,...,v_k)$. Without using induction I would simply prove, in the $=>$ direction, that since $v_1,....,v_k$ are linearly independent, it follows that $v_j \neq$ span$(v_1,...,v_{j-1},v{j+1},...,v_k)$ and therefore span$(v_1,...,v_{j-1},v{j+1},...,v_k)$ is a proper subset of span$(v_1,...,v_j,...,v_k)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This a proof without induction:

- The case **if** is straightforward;
- The case **only if** by **contrapositive**: so assume that:
  $v_j$ is a linear combination of $(v_1,..,v_{j-1},v_{j+1},..,v_k)$
  hence 
  $$\operatorname{span}(v_1,..,v_{j-1},v_{j+1},..,v_k) = \operatorname{span}(v_1,...,v_{j-1},v_j,v_{j+1},...,v_k)$$